# Emulate Default Object#inspect Output?

Tags: ruby

```
o = Object.new
o.instance_eval { @str = "foo" }
p o # => #<Object:0x5dd1a0 @foo="bar">
```

This is good. Calling `p` with an object as an argument prints the output of the objects `inspect` method. But, unfortunately, if the object has a `to_s` method overridden then it will output the output of that:

```
class << o
  def to_s; @str; end
end
p o.to_s # => "foo"
p o # => foo
```

So to fix this, we have to define an `inspect` method on our object:

```
class << o
  def inspect; "blah"; end
end
p o # => "blah"
```

How would I make my object's `inspect` method output the default Ruby way as shown in line 3 of my first code example?

The closest I have is the below, but I'm not sure if it's quite right

```
class << o
  def inspect
    vars = instance_variables.collect { |v| v.to_s << "=#{instance_variable_get(v).inspect}"}.join(", ")
    "#<#{self.class}:0x#{object_id} #{vars}>"
  end
end
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `inspect` method turns out to be surprisingly complex because it needs to properly handle recursive calls to itself.  Here is an implementation based on the [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/) source code that ignores the presence of `to_s`.

```
module DefaultInspect

    Thread.current[:inspected_objects] = {}

    def inspected_objects
      Thread.current[:inspected_objects]
    end

    def inspect_recursion_guard
      inspected_objects[object_id] = true
      begin
        yield
      ensure
        inspected_objects.delete object_id
      end
    end

    def inspect_recursion?
      inspected_objects[object_id]    
    end

    def inspect
      prefix = "#<#{self.class}:0x#{self.__id__.to_s(16)}"

      # If it's already been inspected, return the ...
      return "#{prefix} ...>" if inspect_recursion?

      # Otherwise, gather the ivars and show them.
      parts = []

      inspect_recursion_guard do
        instance_variables.each do |var|
          parts << "#{var}=#{instance_variable_get(var).inspect}"
        end
      end

      if parts.empty?
        str = "#{prefix}>"
      else
        str = "#{prefix} #{parts.join(' ')}>"
      end

      str.taint if tainted?

      return str
    end

end
```

To use this module, you'd do something like this:

```
class Foo

  include DefaultInspect

  def to_s
    @foo
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.instance_eval { @foo = f }
p f     #=> #<Foo:0x8042ad58 @foo=#<Foo:0x8042ad58 ...>>
```

Answer (score 10):

To make the numbers match the original implementation, you just need to left shift the object_id by one bit which is as shown as follow:

```
(object_id << 1).to_s(16)
```

There must be an extra bit used for a flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
irb> o = Object.new.tap{ |o| o.instance_variable_set :@foo, "bar" }
#=> #<Object:0x00000102849600 @foo="bar">

irb> def o.to_s; @foo; end; o
#=> bar

irb> module MyInspect
irb>   def inspect
irb>     vars = instance_variables.map do |n|
irb>       "#{n}=#{instance_variable_get(n).inspect}"
irb>     end
irb>     "#<%s:0x%x %s>" % [self.class,object_id,vars.join(', ')]
irb>   end
irb> end

irb> o.extend MyInspect
#=> #<Object:0x81424b00 @foo="bar">
```

**Edit**: Well, it looks like I came up with basically what you already did. Yours and mine both result in different object_id representations than the original, though.

Let me investigate if there's any way bind to the official implementation and use that.

Comment: The "object_id" is actually the `(void *)` to the object in MRI, and a similar pointer reference in jruby. It is inaccessible in plain ruby code. This is ... odd.